# How can I have the text I enter into each cell automatically appended to the same root URL without creating any new columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I am rephrasing my original question to make it more intelligible.

I put spaces between "https" below because StackOverflow would not allow me to enter the actual URL.

Of course I could enter the text "apple" in cell A1 and then add a link from A1 to `foo.com/Apple` so that I would end up with [Apple](h t t p s://foo.com/Apple) in A1. However, I want that done automatically.

In other words, I want to...

- Go to a cell, and then
- type "apple" on my keyboard, and then
- press enter, and then
- instead of merely seeing "apple" in plain text, I actually I want to see
- "apple" hyperlinked to `foo.com/Apple` like this [Apple](h t t p s://foo.com/Apple).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want you can use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script). Adding a trigger that fires every time column A is edited, getting the entered value and combining it with the `=HYPERLINK(url, link_label)` function, should get what you need.

1. Open the Google Apps Script editor, `Tools>Script Editor`
2. Add the following code

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Check the edit is in column A
  if(e.range.getColumn()==1){
      // Get the values from the onEdit
      let cell = e.range.getA1Notation()
      let value = e.value
      let ss = e.source 
      // Adding as HYPERLINK Formulas
      ss.getRange(cell)
      .setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("https://example.com/${value}","${value}")`)
  }
}
```

###### Documentation

- [HYPERLINK Function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en)
- [onEdit(e) Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [SpreadSheetApp Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: That worked precisely as I had hoped it would. Thank you!

Comment: What country do you live in? What's your hourly rate for Google Sheets consulting? I can be contacted via disposable email at...  emel_from_stackoverflow@yek.anonaddy.com

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX("foo.com/"&B2:B3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. I appreciate that. However, I don't want 2 columns. I only want column B. In other words, I only want to see kiwi and mango. Although I don't want column C to exist, I do want the URL  foo.com/kiwi to be linked to B2 and foo.com/mango to be linked to B3. In other words, when I enter kiwi into B2, I want foo.com/kiwi to be associated with B2.

Comment: are kiwi, mango entered in cells manually or with formula. if manually, than you can solve your issue only with script. otherwise its possible

Comment: I enter kiwi and mango in the cells manually. Did you look at the link I posted in my question... https://itectec.com/webapp/generate-programmatically-hyperlinks-to-sheets-in-google-sheets/ ? I was unable to get it to work.